# error in importing selenium

Tags: python, selenium, geckodriver

- ubuntu 16.04
- selenium-3.4.2
- geckodriver-v0.16

I am trying to run this program:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get('http://seleniumhq.org/')
```

And I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try.py", line 3, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium-3.4.2-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 152, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium-3.4.2-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 98, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium-3.4.2-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 188, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium-3.4.2-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium-3.4.2-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
```

Comment: this might be of your interest https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3884

Comment: What is FF version?

Comment: Also I would suggest using Py 3.5 instead of 2.7